# Delete all rows except 1 the most recent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce-3.5

Want to delete all rows from table except 1 that is the most recent.

This query works fine with SQL Server 2008 Standard edition:

```
DELETE S1 
FROM StateLogs S1, StateLogs S2 
WHERE S1.NodeId = S2.NodeId AND S1.NodeId = {0} AND S1.Modified < S2.Modified
```

But fails on SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5

> *There was an error parsing the query.
>
>   [ Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 11,Token in error = FROM ]*

What is the equivalent for Compact edition?

**EDIT**

Table design http://pastebin.com/Akwpypkm

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard - stop using it

Comment: Ok, thanks. going to using joins than

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Your delete statement appears to have a syntax error, try changing the query from</strike>

```
DELETE S1 FROM ...
```

to

```
DELETE FROM ...
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this statement as a replacement for yours:

```
DELETE FROM StateLogs WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT TOP (1) Id FROM StateLogs ORDER BY Modified DESC)
```

Also just a heads up that you may have problems with insert/update operations against the table based on the schema you've provided because your primary key is larger than the maximum: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This could pretty cause mysterious runtime failures in your application.

Comment: Tried, no luck. There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 23,Token in error = S1 ]

Comment: query in update doesnt execute. think TOP is nut supported in CE

Comment: Looks like it is in CE 3.5 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb686896.aspx, but the syntax requires brackets e.g. 'TOP (1)' instead of 'TOP 1'. Try that

Comment: Thanks that works, but not exactly the same. Correct: DELETE FROM StateLogs WHERE NodeId = {0} AND Id NOT IN (SELECT TOP (1) Id FROM StateLogs WHERE NodeId = {0} ORDER BY Modified DESC)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
DELETE  a
FROM    [StateLogs] a
        LEFT JOIN
        (   
            SELECT NodeID, MAX([Modified]) maxDate
            FROM [StateLogs]
            GROUP BY NodeID
        ) b ON a.nodeID = b.NodeID AND
                a.[Modified] = b.maxDate
WHERE   b.NodeID IS NULL
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
DELETE  
FROM    [StateLogs] 
WHERE   NodeID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT NodeID
            FROM
                    (   
                        SELECT NodeID, MAX([Modified]) maxDate
                        FROM [StateLogs]
                        GROUP BY NodeID
                    ) s
        )
```

Comment: No luck. There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = FROM ]